# The notion of mapping cylinder

Tags: algebraic-topology

This may be a weird question but I really want to know the answer:

Hatcher p.2:

[image]

Why is the name 'cylinder' used in this instance? I don't think that this quotient space, namely the mapping cylinder, is homeomorphic to a cylinder. At the beginning of the chapter, he says that "... it should be read in this informal spirit, skipping bits here and there." So should I just ignore this?

Comment: Even simpler: have you understood why the mapping cone is a "cone"? :)

Comment: I haven't heard such a thing...

Comment: It is another construction in topology which is normally introduced before/with the mapping cylinder. Please refer to  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mapping_cone_(topology) if you are interested in its definition.

Comment: I'm not sure why this is up for closure. It seems to me that questions asking about the motivation behind notation and nomenclature are perfectly valid on the site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is called a cylinder only really to help with intuition. It is only homeomorphic to an actual cylinder ($S^1\times I$) when we have a map $f\colon S^1\rightarrow S^1$ from the circle to itself, and $f$ is a homeomorphism.

You will later also come across the notion of a *mapping torus* which is a mapping cylinder of a map from a space to itself, but where we then identify the 'boundary space' with respect to the map. That is, if $f\colon X\rightarrow X$ is a continuous map, then the mapping torus $\mathcal{M}_f$ is the space $(X\times I)/(x,0)\sim(f(x),1)$.

In the same way, this construction is only homeomorphic to an actual torus if we have a map $f\colon S^1\rightarrow S^1$ from the circle to itself, and $f$ is a homeomorphism.

Answer (score 5):

First, one constructs a cylinder over the space $X$, that is, $X\times I$ (here $I=[0,1]$). Then one maps the top of the cylinder into $Y$. You can think on it as gluing the top $X\times \{1\}$ with the image $f(X)$.

Comment: Makes sense: so here the space homemorphic to a cylinder is the quotient space obtained from $X\times I$, right?

Comment: @Bedi, What is (up to homeomorphism) the mapping cylinder of a constant map $f:S^1\to S^2$?

Comment: It is the quotient space of $(S^1\times I)\cup S^2$ obtained by identifying the top of the cylinder $S^1\times I$ with a point in $S^2$.

Comment: In particular, it is homeomorphic to the wedge sum $D\vee S^2$ where $D$ is a closed disk.

Comment: Since $D$ is contractible, it has the same homotopy type of $S^2$, which is not homotopy equivalent to the cylinder $S^1\times I$. So they can not be homeomorphic.